# Parse serial port data

Tags: c, api

I am using C, which reads the data on the serial port ok. But as with serial port the data is not always the same length. I would like to read up until `\n\r`. The buffer `char szBuff[10]` which is declared at the top of the program contains the data from the serial port from the `Readfile()` method.

I was going to put a `(while != "\n")` to fill up a temporary buffer but will not work. I have also tried to print out individual elements of of `szBuff` to see whats happening) but that crashes the program.

```
    void ReadSerialPort (void){

      strcpy(szBuff, "");
      dwBytesRead = 0;
      char temp;

      //printf("Reading Port %s...", portName);
      if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, bufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
      // Error occurred. Inform user
       printf("Error occurred during read\n");
      }


      if((int) dwBytesRead == 0)
       printf("0 Characters Read\n");
      else
       //printf("Read String: %s, Number of Characters: %d\n\n", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);
      // printf("%s ", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);

      while(szBuff != "\n")
        fill buffer

        temp = szBuff[1];
         printf( szBuff);
         printf( temp);
}
```

Why cant the individual elements be printed out and why cant the while search through for `\n` or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your use of codeblocks is unrelated (it's an IDE). The lack of braces in your example is concerning - due to comments that `if ... else` will be attached to the `while` - be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that are keeping you from seeing your data printed out.

***1)*** read *[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)* because as is you code will not compile, and with its current formatting, is difficult to read

***2)*** The use of `{}` in your example would be an improvement as well.  As is, your intentions are ambiguous.  For example, surround the `if...else` to keep execution flow from jumping directly to the `while` statement:

```
  if((int) dwBytesRead == 0)
  {
       printf("0 Characters Read\n");
  }
  else
  {
       //printf("Read String: %s, Number of Characters: %d\n\n", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);
       // printf("%s ", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);
  }
```

***3)***  There is not enough for me to compile, and I am assuming you have posted some pseudo code, but in the statement:

```
while(szBuff != "\n")
        fill buffer //pseudo code?
```

the string buffer `szBuff` being tested using `!=` will not work, and this is probably not what you intended anyway, but just in case:

Use *[strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)* to determine if string contains the newline character.

```
while(strstr(szBuff, "\n") == NULL)
        fill buffer //pseudo code?
```

Or, (per suggestions in comments) use *[strchr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)*:

```
char *tmp = NULL;
while(strchr(szBuff, '\n') == NULL)
        fill buffer //pseudo code?
```

A potentially better approach (and what you probably intended) may be to use the character form: `\n` (single quotes) along with the `dwBytesRead` variable, and do a comparison.

```
for(i=0;i<dwBytesRead;i++)
{
    if(szBuf[i] != '\n')
    {
          temp = szBuff[i];
          printf("%c", temp);//note format string
    }
    printf("%s\n", szBuff);
    ...
```

Note, `printf` needs to be told how to interpret the thing you want printed.  because `szBuff` is type  `char *` (or should be), the statement:

```
printf( szBuff); // will likely show results in this case but...
printf("%s\n", szBuff); //an explicit format specifier is recommended.
```

And

```
printf( temp );  // needs a format string to tell printf  temp is type char
```

Comment: `strchr()` would be a more lightweight alternative to `strstr()`

Comment: never _ever_ encourage people to use an random 'string' as the format string for `printf()` - it should read `printf("%s", szBuff)` - otherwise here lies an attack vector / SEGFAULT / etc...

Comment: @Attie - Thank you.  Both good, and useful comments.  Have edited answer on both points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that nice clear advice, it really helped me solve the issue with regards to the coding. With regards to the "character overrun" (if there is such a term) from the serial port, it was to do with the amount of bytes being read and as the data length was alternating a fixed data buffer would not work. I decided to do one byte at a time and check fr the termination character as it came in. I put a while loop around to determine end of line. There is also a while 1 loop to run forever with samples coming in every second. It works quiet well.

```
void ReadSerialPort (void){

  strcpy(szBuff, "");
  dwBytesRead = 0;
  char temp;
  int i;
  int check = 1;

  while(1){
    while(check == 1){

          //printf("Reading Port %s...", portName);
          if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, bufSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
          // Error occurred. Inform user
           printf("Error occurred during read\n");
          }

          if((int) dwBytesRead == 0)
           printf("0 Characters Read\n");
          else
           //printf("Read String: %s, Number of Characters: %d\n\n", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);
          // printf("%s ", szBuff, (int) dwBytesRead);

          for(i=0;i<dwBytesRead;i++){
            if(szBuff[i] == '\r'){
                check = 0;
            }
            else{
                temp = szBuff[i];
                printf( "%c",temp);
            }
          }
    }
    check = 1;
    Sleep(1000);
  }
```

}